# Resume after hibernate: monitor signal out-of-range

Tags: 11.04, hibernate

I normally shut down the family Ubuntu 11.04 pc rather than hibernate, but my daughter didn't realise that and put the machine into hiberate. Now when we turn it back on, I see the POST output from the machine's BIOS, then the monitor just displays "input signal out of range" and we can't do interact with anything. This state has survived several power-off cycles, so I presume that the OS is keeping the hibernated session state somewhere, and because I haven't successfully managed to boot the pc it's still there.

I'm currently running the machine from a live CD, so I can eliminate hardware failure as a problem. This means I can also make changes to the on-disk installation, but I'm not sure where to look. Where would Ubuntu store the hibernated session? Can I just delete that file? Any other suggestions as to how I can, er, restore normality? :)  As a last resort I can re-install 11.04, but I'd like to fix, or at least understand, the problem before I do that.

Comment: I found this thread - claims the solution is to reformat the linux-swap partition when using the live-cd.  I've no experience of this though so perhaps treat with caution.  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1712372

Comment: What kind of monitor do you use?

Comment: Sadly, reformatting the swap partition did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you get into the Grub2 menu (ideally from your hard disk, otherwise from your LiveCD)? Try holding down the Shift key while booting!

If yes: In Grub2, select your Hard Disk Linux installation, press the 'e' (edit) key, then add "noresume" to the kernel parameters. Now it should boot without resuming from the hibernate image.